# Create Magento 2 Upgrade Script to add/update new field into custom module table

Tags: module, magento2, setup-script, setup, upgrade-script

Anybody have any idea/suggestion about creating Magento 2(CE Stable version) Upgrade Script(in custom-module) for adding/updating new field into custom table ?

I know about "InstallSchema" but is there something like "UpgradeSchema" for upgrading the module tables ?

Please explain in detail with examples.

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar Your answer was very helpful. Thanks for the head-start.
Next I have gone through a little more deep inside and found that, we should use <i><b>changeColumn</b></i> method while we change the column name or name & definition both.
And we should use <i><b>modifyColumn</b></i> to change definition of column. More details at <i>Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface</i>
Example at <i>Magento\SalesRule\Setup\UpgradeSchema</i> Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

create a `app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Setup\UpgradeSchema.php` and run upgrade command

when ever version was changed just change in module.xml and in UpgradeSchema.php add one more if condition with version compare

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {

            // Changes here.
        }
```

so when you run upgrade command it will run `UpgradeSchema.php` file and in that it will compare the version based on that version it will execute the code

ex

```
<?php

namespace Sugarcode\Test\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
         $tableName = $setup->getTable('testtable');
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.0') < 0) {
            // Changes here.
        }

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {

            // Changes here.
        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.2', '<')) {
              if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
                $connection = $setup->getConnection();
                /* $connection->addColumn(
                    $tableName,
                    'updated_at',
                    ['type' => Table::TYPE_DATETIME,'nullable' => false, 'default' => '', 'afters' => 'created_at'],
                    'Updated At'
                ); */
                $connection->changeColumn(
                    $tableName,
                    'summary',
                    'short_summary',
                    ['type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT, 'nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Short Summary'
                );
                // Changes here.
            }
        }


        $setup->endSetup();

    }
}
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Sugarcode_Test" setup_version="2.0.2" schema_version="2.0.2" />
    </config>
```

if it works accept the answer by clicking right symbol

Comment: @pradeep-kumar The column comment is where addColumn and changeColumn expect the schema name.  `public function addColumn($tableName, $columnName, $definition, $schemaName = null);`. You can put the comment 'Updated At' in the $definition array like `['comment' => 'Updated At']`.

Comment: @Pradeep, My version is "1.0.0", so if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0', '<')) {} now it will work or not?

Comment: what is the older version , if older version is less then 1.0.0 then it works