# SQl is not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, table

I am upgrading my table with new version and changed config version too,

getting error :PDOException Object
(
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 42000

here is my query :

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` CHANGE COLUMN  `create_at` TIMESTAMP;");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` CHANGE COLUMN  `punch_in_time` TIMESTAMP;");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` CHANGE COLUMN  `punch_out_time` TIMESTAMP;");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` ADD `manager_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL ;");

$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

want to change DATATYPE and add one column in existing table.

Comment: This answer will help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92935/create-magento-2-upgrade-script-to-add-update-new-field-into-custom-module-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` CHANGE `create_at` `create_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` CHANGE `punch_in_time` `punch_in_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` CHANGE `punch_out_time` `punch_out_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` ADD `manager_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL;");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` CHANGE `create_at` `create_at` TIMESTAMP;");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` CHANGE `punch_in_time` `punch_in_time` TIMESTAMP;");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` CHANGE `punch_out_time` `punch_out_time` TIMESTAMP;");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `asm_tracker` ADD `manager_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL;");
$installer->endSetup();
```

**Note:** Please add "NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use below code after `TIMESTAMP`:

```
NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```