# Add column Upgrade Schema Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, upgradeschema

I want to insert new field for database table in my custom extension using upgrade schema by following this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92942/51758),but i got an error saying :

```
  [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Category Depth.l  
  ime_eleveniacategory' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `Category Depth`.`  
  lime_eleveniacategory`
```

here's my code:

```
namespace Test\TestAgain\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.0", "<")) {
        //Your upgrade script
        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
          $tableName = $setup->getTable('lime_eleveniacategory'); 
          if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
                $connection = $setup->getConnection();
                $connection->addColumn(
                    $tableName,
                    'category_depth',
                    ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,'nullable' => false, 'afters' => 'category_name'],
                    'Category Depth'
                );
            }
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you created lime_eleveniacategory table?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya yes the table is there in database

Comment: please share your full code file

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya check my updated code

Comment: i have updated answer please check.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
namespace Test\TestAgain\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.0", "<")) {
        //Your upgrade script
        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
          $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('lime_eleveniacategory'),
                'category_depth',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'length' => 10,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Category Depth'
                ]
            );
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

You can get more details here also, [Upgrade Database table](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-upgrade-database-in-magento-2/)

Comment: hello, i have done the same thing but column is not added to table.

Comment: How to create new table using upgradeschema. i have module already

Comment: hello, @Rakesh, how to add the new columns in between the exiting columns?

Comment: @Rakesh How can I pass version there? I'm saying about 1.0.1

Comment: In my module.xml setup_version="2.0.0"

Comment: what will happen if we use "<=" instead of just "<" ?

Answer (score 3):

One more thing to do here. Update `module.xml` version. And upgrade setup, do reindexing and delete cache. It will work.

Answer (score 3):

To Add multiples columns

```
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.1.1', '<')) {
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('reply_newsletter_subscriber'),
            'field_1',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 255,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Field_1'
            ]

        );
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('reply_newsletter_subscriber'),
            'field_2',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 255,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Field_2'
            ]
        );
    }
    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
    <?php


namespace Test\TestAgain\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $quoteSetupFactory;
    protected $salesSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory,
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
         $quoteInstaller = $this->quoteSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'quote_setup', 'setup' => $setup]);
         $salesInstaller = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'sales_setup', 'setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        $setup->startSetup();
        $quoteInstaller->addAttribute('quote', 'custom_column', ['type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT]);
        $salesInstaller->addAttribute('order', 'custom_column', ['type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT]);
        $setup->endSetup();


        }
}
```

OR

```
<?php


namespace Test\TestAgain\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{


    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {


         $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        $connection->addColumn($installer->getTable('quote'), 'custom_column', [
            'type'     => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment'  => 'Custom Column Name'
        ]);
        $connection->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_order'), 'custom_column', [
            'type'     => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment'  => 'Custom Column Name'
        ]);

        $installer->endSetup();


        }
}
```

Note: If you face any issue, it may be due to the module that you have already installed. As you know, if the module is already installed then setup:upgrade command does not install schema. You will need to look into your setup_module table, delete your module from the table and re-run the php bin/magento setup:upgrade command.