# Magento 2 : how can we use of setup:db-schema:upgrade?

Tags: magento2, cli, command-line

Can we add or update the database schema and if yes, so can anyone give example?

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade Script: UpgradeSchema**

UpgradeSchema classes is difference with the Install classes because they will run every time the module upgrade. So we will need to check the `attribute setup_version` in `module.xml` at `app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/` and separate the script by each version.

In this example, we will change the attrubute `setup_version` to `1.2.0`.

File:   `app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.2.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

File: `app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade( SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.2.0', '<')) {
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable( 'mageplaza_helloworld_post' ),
                'test',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'length' => '12,4',
                    'comment' => 'test',
                    'after' => 'status'
                ]
            );
        }



        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

In this class, we use the `upgrade()` method which will be run every time the module is upgraded. We also have to compare the version to add the script for each version.

**Reference Links**

1. [Add column Upgrade Schema Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169408/add-column-upgrade-schema-magento-2)
2. [How to Create Setup, Upgrade, Uninstall Script in Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-create-sql-setup-script.html)
3. [How to Add an Extra Column in Your Existing Magento 2 Table?](https://www.envisionecommerce.com/blog/how-to-add-an-extra-column-in-your-existing-magento-2-table/)

> **You may checkout below link, if you are using Magento 2.3**
>
> Before Magento 2.3, extension developers were required to write code (PHP scripts) to change the database schema. The following types of scripts existed before Magento 2.3:
>
> - InstallData and InstallSchema scripts, which are executed the first time a module is installed.
> - UpgradeData and UpgradeSchema incremental scripts, which supplement an existing module schema.
> - Recurring scripts, which are executed each time you install or upgrade Magento.
>
> [Configure declarative schema](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html)

Comment: Supravat , what about db version???

Comment: What exactly you want me explain?

Comment: I can do the same stuff with s:up after changing setup_version in module.xml then why to use setup:db-schema:upgrade?

Comment: `setup:upgrade`  is uses for *Upgrades the Magento application, DB data, and schema* & `setup:db-schema:upgrade` is uses for *Installs and upgrades the DB schema*