# SchemaUpgrade issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, upgradeschema

Today I'm learning Upgrading schema and Upgrading data, for this I am created simple table with version`0.0.1` and it's working fine. Later I written code  for `UpgradeSchema`. But it is not working for me. For this stuff I have written below code.

**UpgradeSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace Training\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){

        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "0.0.1", "<")) {
            //Your upgrade script
        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.1', '>')) {
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('helloworld'),
                'long_description',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'comment' => 'Long Description'
                ]
            );
        }
        $installer->endSetup();

    }

}
```

after this I run the  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` CLI Command. it's working fine and `setup_module` table also converted versions as below.

1. Previously `Training_HelloWorld` `0.0.1` `0.0.1`
2. After upgrade command `Training_HelloWorld` `0.1.1` `0.1.1` converted successfully.

but My table is not added new column.

Could you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Comment: hi @ manoj please let me know whether u have created the table alreadey in db?

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA Yes, I have.

Comment: please check the modue.xml file version https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92935/create-magento-2-upgrade-script-to-add-update-new-field-into-custom-module-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below code to your version condition

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.1') < 0) {
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('helloworld'),
            'long_description',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 255,
                'nullable' => false,
                'comment' => 'Long Description'
            ]
        );
    }
```

You need to add previous version value (0.0.1) to setup_module table.

Run setup:upgrade command and check.

Comment: Still not working..

Comment: see my updated answer.